# AWS Beanstalk redirect www to non-www with Apache

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed my app creating a AWS Beanstalk configuration with Tomcat and Apache 2.4. I've also succeeded with installing Letsencrypt certificate and enabling https. HTTP/2 is also enabled and works fine. The only thing I'm stuck with is about redirecting www to non-www.
I've tried to add the appropriate config in the war - **.ebextensions\httpd\conf.d\ssl.conf** which is:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule http2_module modules/mod_http2.so
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
  Protocols h2 http/1.1
  <Proxy *>
    Require all granted
  </Proxy>

  ServerName example.com
  SSLEngine             on
  SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
  SSLCipherSuite           EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
  SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLHonorCipherOrder   On

  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
  Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  RewriteEngine On
  Redirect 301 / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

It actually redirects, but... It redirects once! Then the client receives a certificate from example.com, and the next call to www.example.com fails because of the "wrong" certificate produced for the resource without www. As a result SEO checkers fails the 301 check.

My question - is there a way to configure the redirect with Apache?
Is the approach of s3 + Cloudfront is the only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So I've finally found a way to set up a proper 301 redirect from www. site version to non-www without s3 buckets and Cloudfront.

So from the question description Apache redirects resources fine, and after browser getting a certificate for the example.com it actually rejects **subdomains**. What I've missed is that another certificate can be generated and used.

The first step is to generate a certificate:

```
certbot certonly -d *.example.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns
```

The nuance is that you have to pass a challenge. It will ask to add a CNAME record to your hosted zone:

```
Please deploy a DNS TXT record under the name
_acme-challenge.domain.com with the following value:

cxAGAsIvxQggW5FRAqUJfjsnknsYBjb3

Before continuing, verify the record is deployed.
```

having added the record hit the Enter button, and you will get the certificate installed.

Don't forget to restart Apache!
Here you go! The www.example.com now is redirected to example.com.